gulp template precompile broken
In the process of trying to update the following I have broken it. I changed require to import but it is obvious that I need to do more - can anyone help? It currently reports
TypeError: template.precompile is not a function

import gulp from 'gulp';
import insert from 'gulp-insert';
import rename from 'gulp-rename';
import template from 'gulp-template';

// Compile all *.ejs files to pre-compiled templates and append *.js to the filename.
gulp.task('templates', () =>
  gulp.src('./src/**/*.ejs')
    .pipe(template.precompile({
      evaluate: /\{%([\s\S]+?)%\}/g,
      interpolate: /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g,
      escape: /\{\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}\}/g,
      variable: 'ctx'
    }))
    .pipe(insert.prepend('Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {\n' +
      '  value: true\n' +
      '});\n' +
      'exports.default='))
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: '.ejs.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'))
);

